# How to get the memory overhead of a string object in JVM. I got an wrong answer

Tags: java

I have calculated the simple "abcd" that used JVM memory is 32 Byte.The 24 Byte is wrong.
Consider a simple string “abcd” that would take 4 bytes to store using UTF-8 encoding. JVM encodes each character using 2 bytes with UTF-16 encoding, and each String object also contains a 12 byte header and 8 byte hash code, as illustrated by the following output from the the Java Object Layout tool.

```
*java.lang.String object internals:
OFFSET  SIZE   TYPE DESCRIPTION                    VALUE
     0     4        (object header)                ...
     4     4        (object header)                ...
     8     4        (object header)                ...
    12     4 char[] String.value                   []
    16     4    int String.hash                    0
    20     4    int String.hash32                  0
```

From above, I got an object whose initial size is 24 byte, and plus 8 byte of the "abcd" is 32 byte. And it's wrong. Why?

Comment: It is also worth noting that different Java versions use different String representations, and 32 vs 64 bit JVMs can also make a difference.

Comment: What is your question?

Answer (score 1):

The `String` object is indeed 24 bytes, but notice that it has a reference  to a `char[]` object (the reference itself is 4 bytes), at offset 12:

```
12     4 char[] String.value                   []
```

Presumably, the author counted the size of the `char[]` too, which is not an unreasonable thing to do.

How big is `char[]`? Let's use JOL:

```
java -jar jol-cli.jar internals [C
```

(`[C` is the name of `char[].class`)

This produces the output:

```
[C object internals:
 OFFSET  SIZE   TYPE DESCRIPTION                               VALUE
      0    16        (object header)                           N/A
     16     0   char [C.<elements>                             N/A
Instance size: 16 bytes
```

JOL assumes the array is empty, but of course in our case the array has 4 characters (8 bytes in total when encoded in UTF-16), so the `char[]` also as big as 24 bytes.